# How to extract attribute name when field value is known from XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, automation, attributes

I need to extract attribute name when field name is given. Suppose if I have field name Testing, then I need to extract attribute value for name corresponding to that field. In this case attribute value will be "SN_Name"

```
<RequirementFieldList>
  <field name="SN_Name">Testing</field>
  <field name="Email1">Test1_User</field>
  <field name="Email2">na</field>
  <field name="Email3">na</field>
  <field name="Email4">na</field>
</RequirementFieldList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give the value of the name attribute if the value of field attribute is "Testing"

```
.//field[contains(.,"Testing")]/@name
```